# Локализация сайта: как реализовать?

Tags: php

Товарищи комсомольцы!

Нужно подключить конфиг (например, lang_ru.ini) глобально к mvc, чтобы всюду можно было использовать конструкцию типа $lang['SITENAME'], $lang['CONTACTS'] и тому подобное.

Не могу сообразить где это единожды подключить — в виде, контроллере или ещё где.

Например:

```
class Local
{
    public $lang;

    public function __construct()
    {
        return $lang = parse_ini_file('application/config/lang_ru.ini');
    }
}
```

`$lang` — массив, как передавать это всё дело туда, где встречается статичный текст, вроде сообщений, тайтлов статических страниц, названий кнопок и пр.?

Вот такая структура приложения (упрощённая схема):

```
/index.php
/app/core/model.php
/app/core/controller.php
/app/core/view.php
/app/core/router.php
/app/controllers/MainController.php
/app/controllers/AdminController.php
/app/models/MainModel.php
/app/models/AdminModel.php
/app/views/layout.php
/app/views/post.php
/app/config/routes.php
/app/config/lang_ru.ini
/app/models/MainModel.php
/app/lib/Db.php
/app/lib/Pagination.php
/app/lib/Local.php
```

Comment: Чтоб определить где подключать, нужно быть знакомым с вашим приложением.. а так - в AppServiceProvider подключите :)

Comment: А я вам сейчас нарисую, дополню вопрос :)

Comment: используйте di контейнер и инжектите через него свой объект локализации

Comment: От списка файлов приложения яснее не стало... попробуйте подключить в контроллере, от которого наследуете остальные контроллеры.. так, на вскидку если

Comment: Jour, а как это сделать правильно? Я так понимаю, нужно в классе контроллера добавить `use application\lib\Local;`, а потом писать в нужном месте `$loc['CONTACTS']`? А где создать объект класса, чтобы было видно глобально?